# Invoke "ToString" method by reflection

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve the MethodInfo "ToString" as follows:

```
MethodInfo method = MyType.GetMethod("ToString", 
                                     BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

An exception is being thrown "Ambiguous match found".

Comment: Any reason you can't simply call `ToString`? Seeing as every object has one...

Comment: What's `MyType` anyway? That type may have overloads for `ToString()`, but it'll always have the parameterless one.

Comment: @Oded could be trying to get at one with a different signature?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - Possibly, though the OP doesn't mention, one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToString()` is a member of `System.Object` and thus it is one of the very few methods that you don't need reflection for when you wat to call it on an unknown Type.

The exception is in the overloads for Tostring (ie  `int.ToString(string format)` but to call one of those you have to know which one you're looking for.

And those overlaods cause the error you see. You will have to be specific.

Comment: Excuse me... I've edited your response thinking it was mine. I hope I've rollbacked my edit correctly .

Answer (score 9):

Your type contains multiple `ToString()` overloads and `GetMethod` does not know which one you want.

Use the following syntax to specify that you want the overload that does not take any parameters:

```
MethodInfo method = myType.GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
```

Note: Since `ToString()` is defined on `System.Object`, you do not need reflection to call it on an object of unknown type:

```
object myObject = ...;
string s = myObject.ToString(); // works
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably there are more than one `ToString()` methods. For example `double` has four variants (the override of `virtual object.ToString()` plus three variants)

Try

```
var variants = MyType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
               .Where(p => p.Name == "ToString");
```

it will return all the variants of `ToString`

or, if you know the parameters of "your" `ToString`

```
var toString = MyType.GetMethod("ToString", 
               BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, 
               null, arrayOfParametersType, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that you want the one with no arguments:

```
var method = MyType.GetMethod("ToString", 
                              new Type[0]);
```

`BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance` is the default values, no need to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyType).GetMethod("ToString", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

That actually works for me...

You probably have an overload(s) on ToString.
Since you can have multiple ToString methods (overloads) that are public, this line could return multiple ToString-methods.

You'd have to use something like:
    GetMethod(string name, Type[] types)

Where Type[] contains an array of the types the method you're searching for has (in your case none)

(Thanks to comments, also learned something from this :)

Comment: On it's own the code is fine.  It fails when it finds more than one method called "ToString" within its search parameters: Public | Instance.

Answer (score 0):

`ToString` can be overloaded. And on many types it is.

First you should check if the `ToString` you want to call is either the overridden `object.ToString()` or [`IFormattable.ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring.aspx), since you can simply avoid reflection in these cases.

You can use an overload of `GetMethod` that takes the `Type[] types` parameter to choose which overload of `ToString` you want.

For example you can use [`GetMethod("ToString",new Type[]{})`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hy0h0z1.aspx) to get the parameterless `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check that if you want to override `ToString()` you really use the `override` keyword:

```
class MyType
{
     public override string ToString()
     {
         return "Whatever";
     }
 }
```

Otherwise you are hiding the object.ToString() version rather than really overriding.

Answer (score 0):

In a scenario such as this, when you know the method exists (potentially with a number of overloads to complicate matters), it can be helpful to use a [Reflection helper library](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com) that does the hard work for you.

For instance, Fasterflect allows you to simply do the following in order to invoke a method using the "best available match" given the supplied parameters (in the example below, the optional argument 42 represents some value that you want to use when invoking the method):

```
var obj = ...
var result = obj.TryCallMethodWithValues( "ToString", 42 );
```

In my experience, using a well-tested library instead of hand-coding (in this case, reflection) pays off rather quickly.

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to the Fasterflect project.